# middleware for one specific method in controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have middleware `Auth` that is in `App\Http\Middleware\`

In my kernel i added him like:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'Groups' => \App\Http\Middleware\Groups::class,
        'Auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Auth::class,
    ];
```

This middleware contains

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Auth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if( !auth()->check() )
        {
            return abort(404);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And in my controller method I use

`$this->middleware('Auth');`

But this doesn't work at all.

And when I take my `'Auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Auth::class,` and place it into `protected $middlewareGroups` like `\App\Http\Middleware\Auth::class,` it works. But for every single page. So when I am not logged it all time abort404.

What is wrong here?
I can't see, it looks fine to me.

But this middleware doesn't work for this method in which I have `$this->middleware('Auth');`

I am not logged in but page appears as normal.

And there should be abort404 fired cuz I am not logged

What made I wrong?

Comment: You already have that kind of middleware set up from stock Laravel, you want to take a closer look at stock `auth` and `guest` middlewares thats item 0 and 4 in `$routeMiddleware` array.

Comment: @Kyslik this works when I place it into constructor, why I can't place it directly into method?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem that you have when you added the middleware to `$middlewareGroups` is explained in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware)

> Out of the box, the web middleware group is automatically applied to
>   your routes/web.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.

And if you want the middleware for just one action in the cotroller you can bind the middleware to the route :

```
Route::get('yourRout', 'YourController@actionX')->middleware('auth');
```

Or you can add it in constructor of your controller :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['edit']]);
}
```

Or you can try ( Since Laravel 5.3) :

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->only(['edit']);
    }
```

Comment: But I have resource route `Route::resource('uzytkownik', 'UsersController');` And I need to assign it to action UsersController@edit

Comment: So isn't it possible to assign middleware to one method of resource controller route in routes?

Comment: For now, you must add the middlewares to the constructor :)

Comment: Great! Even we can specify middleware('auth')->except['something'] which methods to not check the auth

Comment: Actually this is the correct way for using the exception:

```php
$this->middleware('guest', [
    'except' => ['demo']
]);
```